# Add two numbers represented by linked lists, carry value didn't pass to the next calculation

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

I wrote the following code to calculate sum of two numbers represented by linked list. take a simplest case as example, two same linked list are `3->8->2->1-> null`, the output was supposed to be `7->6->4->2->null`, but the result I got is `6->6->4->2->null`. please help!! Thank you!

```
public ListNode addListF(ListNode l1, ListNode l2, int carry)  {

        if (l1 == null && l2 == null && carry == 0) {
            return null;
        }
       ListNode result = new ListNode();
        int len1 = l1.length(l1);
        int len2 = l2.length(l2);

        /*pad the shorter list with 0*/
       if (len1 < len2) {
            l1 = padList(l1, len2 - len1);
        } else {
            l2 = padList(l2, len1 - len2);
        } 

        result.next = addListF(l1.next, l2.next, carry);
        int sum = carry + l1.data + l2.data;
        result.data = sum % 10;
        carry = sum / 10;

        return result;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in this case is that carry is always zero. Putting the recursive call after calculations would make the carry apply incorrectly, as higher order digits would get added first.

One way of passing back the carry from the lower order summation to higher order one would be to use wrapper for carry, so that the assigned carry value is not lost once the recursive call returns. To do so, create class:

```
class CarryWrap {
    int value = 0;
}
```

Also modify addListF() method as such:

```
public ListNode addListF(ListNode l1, ListNode l2, CarryWrap carry) {

    /**same statement before recursive call**/

    result.next = addListF(l1.next, l2.next, carry);
    int sum = carry.value + l1.data + l2.data;
    result.data = sum % 10;
    carry.value = sum / 10;

    return result;
}
```

Before you call the addListF(), do

```
CarryWrap carry = new CarryWrap();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should put the recursive call **after** computing the current data and carry. Otherwise you are passing 0 as carry always.